# Multiple command line arguments in perl when one argument mistakenly takes other argument as its value

Tags: perl

I am working on a perl program (perl 5.8). This program uses command line arguments for its inputs. 
The problem I face is this - I am using multiple command line arguments. 
E.g.

```
tool -f "arg1_val" -p "arg2_val"
```

But in cases when user forgets to specify a value say

```
tool -f -p "arg2_val"
```

Instead of erroring out, it assumes -f = -p

I am using [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long) and the routine GetOptions

```
GetOptions ("f=s" => \$opt_f,
            "p=s" => \$opt_p,
           );
```

Comment: A nice [article about Getopt::Long](http://perltricks.com/article/195/2015/10/21/Professional-scripts-are-a-snap-with-Getopt--Long/).

Answer (score 4):

You should use `:` instead of `=`.

You should check "Summary of Option Specifications" in [`Getopt::Long`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). This is from [`GetOptions`](http://search.cpan.org/~chips/perl5.004_05/lib/Getopt/Long.pm).

> `=s`: Option takes a mandatory string argument. This string will be assigned to the option variable. Note that even if the string argument
>   starts with - or --, it will not be considered an option on itself.
>
> `:s`: Option takes an optional string argument. This string will be
>   assigned to the option variable. If omitted, it will be assigned ""
>   (an empty string). If the string argument starts with - or --, it will
>   be considered an option on itself.

Below should work. If you ommit any argument, the corresponding variable will be assigned `""`.

```
GetOptions ('f:s' => \$opt_f,
            'p:s' => \$opt_p,
           ) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

# later you can check for argument variable if any option is mendatory for you.
die "No value passed to -f\n" unless($opt_f);
```

Comment: This nails it.  I completely forgot the difference.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the difference. In most of the documents, difference between =s and :s is explained only in terms of optional/non-optional. But it is an important point to remember - "hat even if the string argument starts with - or --, it will not be considered an option on itself"

Answer (score 0):

What error would you expect? The `-f` option has an argument, and the `-p` option wasn't specified.  You have to handle mandatory or extra options yourself:

```
die "Missing -p\n" unless defined $opt_p;
die "Missing -f\n" unless defined $opt_f;
die "Extra arguments @ARGV\n" if @ARGV;
```